# passing a string argument into angularjs ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Not sure how to do this, but I would like to pass a string as an argument into ng-click and then us it as a conditional in the function. so something like this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center mb-5">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click=""><span class="ion-plus-circled mr-2"></span>New</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ng-click="filter_emails('inbox')"><span class="ion-archive mr-2"></span>Inbox</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ng-click=""><span class="ion-paper-airplane align-middle mr-2"></span>Shielded</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then in my controller:

```
$scope.filter_emails = function(category) {
    if (category == "inbox") {
        $scope.grouped = group(inbox($scope.emails));
    }
    else {
        $scope.grouped = group($scope.emails);
    }
}
```

This is not working or I obviously wouldn't be posting the question, so what would the correct approach to this?

Comment: this is definitely functioning correctly in this plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/7nJbExQv3La9Ka8KZSrs?p=preview (all I changed is adding `console.log`).  This isn't a problem with this function; if you are having issues, it's likely in your `group` function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a string enclose it within **`quotes`**

```
ng-click="filter_emails('inbox')"
```

Comment: I updated my code above, this is not working even with the quotes

Comment: try with   if (category === "inbox") {

Comment: can you create a plunker

Comment: working on a full code, but having trouble with plunker getting angular-route.min.js

Comment: ok i have a working plunker now. sorry it took me a minutes https://plnkr.co/edit/MT0182RTJWbqKLeqdODS?p=preview

Comment: check the working demo https://plnkr.co/edit/rGvJhdculX6Kfw95ZGWf?p=preview

Comment: problem was you have placed the function inside the callback, also you have not replaced 'inbox' as i mentioned